# How to do nested navigation in stack navigator from child to another child v5?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-v5

I got stuck at a point where i want to do some nested navigation from child screen to another child screen. Below is my required stack navigation.

```
  Home Screen
     -> Add User
     -> View Users 
          -> No Users(Shown only incase no users found)
          -> Users List(Shown when users Data found)
              ->View Details
```

Below is the code which i tried to replicate the above stack navigator with nested navigation for ViewUsers. But i was confused in implementing from this
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

```
 const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
 function UserDetailsRoot(){
 return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
        <HomeStack.Screen name="No Users" component={NoUsers} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Users List" component={UsersList} />
        <HomeStackScreen  name="User Details" component={UserDetails} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>

   )
 }
 const HomeStackScreen = () => (
<HomeStack.Navigator>
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Home " component={HomeScreen} />
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Add User" component={AddUsers} />
    <HomeStack.Screen name="UserDetailsRoot" component={UserDetailsRoot} />
</HomeStack.Navigator>

);

export default () => (
<NavigationContainer>
    <HomeStackScreen />
</NavigationContainer>
);
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of nesting navigators. In your code your nesting a Stack inside a Stack, which I believe isn't correct. What I'd probably do is something like this

```
const MainStackScreen = () => (
<HomeStack.Navigator>
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Home " component={HomeScreen} />
    <HomeStack.Screen name="AddUser" component={AddUsers} />
    <HomeStack.Screen name="UsersList" component={UsersList} />
    <HomeStack.Screen name="UserDetails" component={UserDetails} />
</HomeStack.Navigator>
);

export default () => (
<NavigationContainer>
    <MainStackScreen />
</NavigationContainer>
);
```

You definitely don't need a screen for "no users" state, I assume that in UsersList you're rendering a `SectionList` or a `FlatList`, so if your API return empty, you can use `ListEmptyComponent` to handle that specific case.

Also nesting navigators is useful when you need to combine features from one navigator with another, for example placing a StackNavigator inside each tab of a TabNavigator is a common pattern. Another case is when you need to render something as a modal over the Stack, in that case you need to add a StackNavigator as a container.

Hope it'll help you :)

Comment: @Madhu Some months have passed, is the answer correct for you? :) If so, could you mark it as correct answer?